# locale switcher languages are not displaying

Tags: symfony, locale, switchers

I am using locale switcher

```
https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/switcher.md
```

And by calling {{ locale_switcher() }} in twig it displays list of my languages... this works fine for every page like /news/ /profile/ whatever ...

Then i have different content for "main root" "/" mysite.com/ if user is logged in or not.

It works when user is logged out .. the locale_switcher display languages... but at the same url .. when i am **logged in** .. **it doesn't work**... and of course work at /home/ etc... even if logged in...

And i have no idea why... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
project_main:
    pattern: /{_locale}
    defaults: 
        _controller: ProjectWebBundle:Main:main
        _locale: %locale%
```